# IntelliJ copy class field names and paste them into method as arguments?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am designing a Vaadin UI component with around 30 components

e.g.

```java
public class MyView {


private TextField foo;
private TextField bar;
private TextField bobby;
private TextField x;
private TextField y;
private TextField z;
private TextField ad;
private TextField nauseum;
private TextField thisisboring;


    public MyView() {
        formview.add(foo,bar,bobby,tables,x,y,z,ad,nauseum,thisisboring);
    }

}
```

I want to add all these fields as arguments into the `formview.add()` method. At the moment I am manually adding each field to this method.

Is there an easier way for IntelliJ to generate all these field names as arguments of a function?

(I really don't want to type 30 fields into a method)

Comment: I do not know if IntelliJ has anything that helps, but in general it looks like hard thing for any IDE to assist. I have myself studied totally different kind of option of creating Form component that autogenerates itself from the Bean using data types. This naturally requires very opionated decisions, and wont work in sophisticated designs, but could give nice RAD solution for some cases https://github.com/TatuLund/ProtoTools/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/addons/tatu/prototools/Form.java

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but use [multi-caret selection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/multicursor.html):

First double click on the first identifier you need, then double click on each following identifier while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> down. You should have all the identifiers you need selected. Copy them to the clipboard using <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Put the caret between the parentheses of `formview.add()`. Don't hold any keys down, so you have only a single caret left. Paste <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. All identifiers will be pasted on separate lines. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click and drag the mouse past the end of the selected lines (except the last one). This should add a caret at the end of every line. Type a <kbd>,</kbd> to add a comma between the pasted identifiers and optionally join lines <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to put the call on a single line.

This should be quite a bit less work than typing everything out.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one naive approach: Declaring it like

`private AbstractField<String> foo, bar, bobby, x, y, z, ad, nauseum, thisisboring;`

and just copy/paste (or if there are multiple field types, at least group the same types)?

Or maybe better approach: as the root of the problem is probably too many parameters, we can encapsulate it:

```
        private FormFields formFields;

        public MyView() {
            formview.add(formFields.asArray());
        }

        public static class FormFields {

            private TextField foo;
            ...

            public Component[] asArray() {
                return new Component[]{foo, bar, bobby, x, y, z, ad, nauseum, thisisboring};
            }
            
            ... //getters etc.
        }
```